# Open CSV File with Different Delimiter

Tags: macos, numbers, csv

I'm currently using the default Numbers application to open my CSVs. My current use case involves a file that I had to use a different type of separator (`|`). Is there any way to change the separator? Right now when I open the file it just puts the entire row in one column.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Numbers you can use any separator when importing csv tables.

On the format sidebar, in the table tab, look for adjust Import settings. Inside it you have delimited options where you can even use custom delimiters

Comment: It's worth noting that this option is only shown when a CSV is already open, and it won't appear for non-CSV files :o)

Comment: no such option in Numbers 10.1 (6913)

Comment: Okay. for this to work you have to click on any cell for this options to appear.

Comment: What do I do when I want to change the delimeter while exporting the file? Right now the way you suggested just changes the actual table that's open but I want to save with a different delimeter.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sed`;  the **S**tream **ED**itor from Terminal.

`sed -i -e 's/"|"/|,"/g' filename`

`s` is used to replace the found expression "|" with ","

`g` is for "global", *meaning  do this to the whole line*. If you omit the `g` option it will only replace the first instance, ignoring the rest

`-i` option is to "edit in place" meaning it changes the file itself.

`-e` option indicates the expression/command to run.

Comment: While this is very helpful if I were to convert the format, it does not help my current use case. I'm asking specifically to be able to use a different separator because my data contains commas. Thanks though, love how you explained what each part of the command helps do (plus I hadn't heard of sed before)

Comment: It's not converting the format, it's still a CSV except that it's using a different separator character

Comment: That's what I meant by format. The separator is the problem here

Comment: That's a limitation of Numbers.  The only option is to work with your data as a CSV file then covert the separators using `sed` through Terminal or use [Excel Online](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) to save it as a CSV with your preferred format.

Answer (score 4):

- open your csv file in Numbers
- You should see a `Adjust Settings` thing pop up, click it
- You'll see an `Import Settings` dialog make sure you click on `Delimited`
- in the Custom Delimiter field add `|`
- Click `Update Table`
- [image: Adjust Settings]

[image]

Comment: But what can we do once the pop-up disappear?

Comment: @MemphisMeng Click anywhere in the table and then click on "Format" (top right) and then scroll down to the bottom, you'll find "Adjust Import Settings..."

Answer (score 1):

Another option, you can open it in OpenOffice/LibreOffice. It lets you pick exactly what the delimiters are. Then once it opens, save a copy in some other format, then you can open it in Pages.

Answer (score 0):

Using the -i option for sed is courageous, but also dangerous. I would recommend the following:

```
sed -e 's/"|"/|,"/g' filename > tmp
```

Then, check that the file tmp is formatted as you wanted it to be. If it is ok, then you can replace the original file with tmp:

```
mv tmp filename
```

Answer (score -2):

Numbers >=5.0 after opening a csv-File you get a floating dialog "Table data was imported. Adjust Settings". When hitting "Adjust settings" you can control the delimiters. Found this solution in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIEmnDvlRwA)

Comment: This answer was already provided in the accepted answer.  To avoid downvotes you might want to edit the accepted answer to add the part about the floating sidebar which is just a different way to get to the same setting.