# Copy and paste issue from Excel to Keynote table

Tags: ms-office, numbers, keynote

I'm having a big issue when copying from multiple Excel cells/rows and then pasting into a Keynote/Numbers table. When I select multiple cells in Excel with named content such as 'David goes to the gym' and then paste into a Keynote/Numbers cell it stretches the content across 5 separate cells as opposed to keeping it in one cell.

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.. I've reinstalled office365 but this hasn't changed anything.

Anyone any ideas on this ?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, can you clarify exactly what you mean by a *keynote/numbers cell*? Do you mean you're trying to paste it into a Numbers spreadsheet, a Keynote table, or a Keynote table that you originally copied and pasted from a Numbers spreadsheet? Also, can you clarify what you mean by *named content* in Excel? Do you mean you're copying a named `range`, or just that you're copying text?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the welcome and apologies if the question was unclear. I meant a table in a numbers or keynote file. Also there's simply text in a multiple rows and when I copy these and input it into the table in either keynote or numbers it's spreading the content across multiple cells, so if in the excel file the column/row read 'David asked a question' then I pasted into the keynote/numbers table it would paste across 4 columns like A - David, B - asked, C - a, D - question, and so on.. Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

Your delimiter in numbers is set to a 'space', so it reads spaces in the sentence as being cell delimiter. Hence, each word goes into a separate cell. You need to change the delimiter to a comma or a tab. Then only values separated this chacter will fill new cells. To change delimiter (taken from [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268051/open-csv-file-with-different-separator/333297)):

> In Numbers you can use any separator when importing csv tables.
>
> On the format sidebar, in the table tab, look for adjust Import settings. Inside it you have delimited options where you can even use custom delimiters